# Anyone have any idea what cable is this?

Tags: cables

This is apparently a network cable of some sort which I couldn't figure out what it is. Here is the damaged end:

[image: damaged end]

And here is the other end:

[image]

It was chopped off accidentally by the contractor and he wasn't sure what is it exactly. Anyone is aware of such cable and how do I reconnect it back? Appreciate it. I tried asking in the network section. Someone suspect that it's a telephone cable?

Comment: What is connected to the other end of that cable?

Comment: i wish i knew @Tyler, the cable is inside the wall.

Comment: ok, what was this end connected to?

Comment: @Tyler looks like an ethernet port or some network devices.  I'm not too sure myself. but if I stare at the cable hole, directly underneath is an ethernet port. But as you can see, it doesn't look like a ethernet cable

Comment: Are you sure thats not a cable "puller"/"pusher" thing?

Comment: @WesleyLee I don't see anything in there or down there for sure. very thin wire but no idea what it does yet. (well, guess cause the wire is chopped off)

Comment: How many conductors? It may be a 2 wire doorbell cable.

Comment: @Passerby good guess! there is no doorbell installed anywhere! so I highly doubt it's a doorbell cable. This building is an office unit but no doorbell from the developer that's for sure. This hole is in the wall when we install additional plug, accidentally got chopped off when we were drilling the wall to lay out the cables

Comment: Looks like a [polymer optical fiber](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_optical_fiber). Maybe a field-bus system?

Comment: @Andreas I'm hoping its not that. How the hell do i reconnect a polymer optical fiber? :(

Comment: @Andreas I don't think it's a POF though. A POF cable doesn't have an electric wire component at the center of the wiring.

Comment: @cylua2 There is no point in reconnecting unless you know what it is supposed to do. POFs are stiffer than litz wire and do always straighten after being bent (unlike solid copper wire). Be careful, bending below 20mm radius will damage it.

Comment: @cylua2 Hmm OK, I was not able to spot the wire.

Comment: @Andreas thanks man! I guess the only way to know what it is, is to ask the developer what this delicate piece of crap does. Appreciate all the helps everyone!

Comment: The other option is that it may be a cable for a security device, a door or window sensor?

Comment: @Andreas i just manage to get the other end of the image uploaded. Is this a POF?

Comment: @Andreas yeah. its a fibre optic cable.

Comment: its call a 2 core indoor drop cable. i have called and asked the supply directly.

Answer (score 4):

From my point of view, looks like an optical fiber from isp. Not very clear on the core view.

The elaborate connector on the other end probably will explain it, if you took that photo to an electrical supply house.

Comment: I was think fiber also + could have been part of a surround sound system.

Comment: 2nd for also thinking fiber - that also explains why you can't see any metal traces in the cable. Be careful, you do NOT want fiber strands in your finger.

Comment: I second that portion about glass fragments, @djsmiley2k.  Once they work their way in, the only way to get them out is to either just let them fester (the body will expel it) or surgery.  Maybe some electrical tape over the cut end would be appropriate.